# Why is grep showing lines that don't match?

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to print out all lines with at least one character that is NOT numeric.

My grep code looks like this: `grep '[^[:digit:]]' GTEST`

Where GTEST is this:

```
TEST 
55 55 Pink
123
sss
aaa
ss aaa ss
a 1 b 2 a b a 
Doop Dap
12 13
77a
59360
```

And the output is exactly what is in GTEST, except with the matching parts of lines (AKA all of the alpha characters) in red.  Instead of displaying the matching characters in red, I /only/ want to print out the lines that contain matching characters.

I've been looking around the `grep` tags (-o, -w, etc), but none of them seem to do it for me.

Am I missing something?

EDITED:

Expected output would be:

```
TEST 
55 55 Pink
sss
aaa
ss aaa ss
a 1 b 2 a b a 
Doop Dap
77a
```

Comment: Every line in your input has at least one character which is not numeric. Do not forget the the space character ` ` is also non-numeric.

Comment: Please provide expected output to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That is, in fact, the output I get.  `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: Which OS are you running? On the Windows command line the ^ character is a special *escape character*, so you need to use ^^ to get ^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your data, I get this output:

```
grep '[^[:digit:]]' file
TEST
55 55 Pink
sss
aaa
ss aaa ss
a 1 b 2 a b a
Doop Dap
12 13
77a
```

You get the `12 13`, since space between `12` and `13` is a non digit character.
This will also give output if you have space before or after digits, like: `123<space>`

To overcome this, you can do like this:

```
grep '[^[:digit:] ]' file
TEST
55 55 Pink
sss
aaa
ss aaa ss
a 1 b 2 a b a
Doop Dap
77a
```

Or even better:

```
grep '[^[:digit:][:blank:]]' file
```